# How to filter page source to get pure HTML - no content (tags only)

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, diff, html

Does anybody know how to get pure HTML structure of given webpage (without content) using JavaScript?

I'm trying to do this in PhantomJS which provides two properties (page.content and page.plainText) - the first one holds content of the web page (with HTML elements tags) and the second one holds content without any HTML tags. Unfortunately there isn't such property which holds pure HTML structure. I was trying to get it by using git diff (difference between page.content and page.plainText), but it's not working as I would expect.

Comment: What is a *pure HTML structure* supposed to be? Are you trying to remove all text nodes? Can you give an example of what you would expect and why do you want this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get html of current page, you should use `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;`.

If you want to get pure html, you can use recursive function to parse whole html structure and create virtual DOM tree and then output its `innerHTML`.

```
var result = document.createElement('html');
var startNode = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];

function parser(node, target) {
   var nodes = node.childNodes;
   for(var i in nodes) {
      var currentNode = nodes[i];
      var nodeName = currentNode.nodeName;
      if(!nodeName || nodeName[0] == '#') continue;
      var newNode = document.createElement(nodeName);
      parser(currentNode, newNode);
      target.appendChild(newNode);
   }
}
parser(startNode, result);
console.log(result.innerHTML);
```